# Step 4 of Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack is taking too much time

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have a total of three machines. I have installed MaaS in one of my machines and the other two machines were added to the MaaS nodes list and kept in ready state.

When I run the fourth step given in the [Installing The Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) Ubuntu documentation, both the machines went to the deployed state.

The Ubuntu OpenStack installer screen is running for too long a time. I don't know to how to proceed. Please help me. I am looking for this to do simple job scheduling in a cloud environment using OpenStack.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu OpenStack requires at least seven machines (not only 2 vnode) with two disks, two of which have two network interfaces (NICs). Install Ubuntu Server on one of the machines with two interfaces. Then after all vnode are in ready status you can continue with installation on Openstack Autopilot. If you hav not this requests you can install that on your virtual enviroment.